# Gaussian functional integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, path-integral

I am trying to understand how a functional integral is carried out. We have

$$F = \frac{1}{2}\sigma \int d^2x|\vec{\nabla} h|^2$$

where $h(\vec{x})$ is a scalar function of the position vector $\vec{x}$. We want to compute the functional integral

$$\langle (h(\vec{y})-h(\vec{0}))^2\rangle=\frac{\int Dh(\vec{x})|h(\vec{y})-h(\vec{0})|^2e^{-F/k_BT}}{\int Dh(\vec{x})e^{-F/k_BT}}$$

It is said that this integral can be computed in Fourier space to yield

$$\langle (h(\vec{y})-h(\vec{0}))^2\rangle=\frac{2k_BT}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2q}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1}{q^2}(1-e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{y}})$$

Could you help me figure our how this integral is carried out?

Comment: Do you understand how to calculate the propagator $\langle h(y)h(0)\rangle$?

Comment: @octonion I don't, unfortunately. Is there an example that I could look at?

Comment: The derivation is a little too long and standard for me to want to type up an answer, but if you have this question as a homework problem you must have gone over Gaussian integrals in your class notes or textbook, so I suggest reviewing that. If you can't find it, take a look at Peskin and Schroeder's textbook leading up to equation (9.27). You will have to make some minor modifications for your problem (you have $m=0$, it is in 2D Euclidean space, and you need to keep track of $\sigma, T$), but that is the general idea.

Comment: @Octonion following the text I think $\langle 0|h(\vec{x_1})h(\vec{x_2})|0\rangle=\frac{k_BT}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2q}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1}{q^2}e^{i\vec{q}\cdot(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})}$ should work because as I understand this gives

$\langle (h(\vec{y})-h(\vec{0}))^2\rangle=\langle 0|h(\vec{y})^2|0\rangle-2\langle 0|h(\vec{y})h(\vec{0})|0\rangle+\langle 0|h(\vec{0})^2|0\rangle=\frac{2k_BT}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2q}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1}{q^2}(1-e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{y}})$

But I'm confused because we have no imaginary number in $e^{-F/k_BT}$ while the caculations are done with $e^{iS}$, thanks

Comment: @dandide, Yes that's right. It's actually more straightforward to do the calculations with $e^{-S}$ instead of $e^{iS}$. If you do the calculations with $e^{-S}$ you will not have the factor of $i$ in (9.27) as you noticed, and you also don't need to worry about that $+i\epsilon$ term in the denominator, which is only there to ensure $e^{iS}$ converges as a Gaussian integral.

Comment: @octonion and sodiumnitrate I tried to replicate roughly what is done in the text but I got lost in a lot of places any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Trying to replicate the steps in the [text](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/483/Peskin,%20Schroesder%20-%20An%20introduction%20To%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory(T).pdf#page=307) the first they do is say that 
$\int d^4x (\partial_{\mu}\phi(x_i))^2-m^2\phi(x_i)=\frac{1}{V}\sum_n(|k_n|^2-m^2)|\phi(k_n)|^2$, simply writing the function as a fourier series should be enough but even so at first I wasn't able until it clicked that this equality is the [plancherel/parseval identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Parseval's_theorem) for derivatives in a multidimensional case, so proving it was [copy-pasting](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlancherelsTheorem.html)

$$
F
=\int d^2x|\partial_{\mu}\phi(x_i)|^2=\int d^2x(\partial_{\mu}(\frac{1}{V}\sum_n e^{-ik_nx_i}\phi(k_n))\partial_{\mu}(\overline{\frac{1}{V}\sum_m e^{-ik_nx_i}\phi(k_m)})
\\=\int d^2x\frac{1}{V^2}\sum_n\sum_m e^{i(k_m-k_n)x_i}k_n\overline{k_m}\phi(k_n)\overline{\phi(k_m)}
=\frac{1}{V}\sum_n\sum_m (\int \frac{d^2x}{V}e^{i(k_m-k_n)x_i})k_n\overline{k_m}\phi(k_n)\overline{\phi(k_m)}
\\=\frac{1}{V}\sum_n\sum_m \delta(k_m-k_n)k_n\overline{k_m}\phi(k_n)\overline{\phi(k_m)}
=\frac{1}{V}\sum_n|k_n|^2|\phi(k_n)|^2
$$

So using norm notation we have shown that
$$
||\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)||\equiv\int d^2x|\partial_{\mu}\phi(x_i)|^2
=\frac{1}{V}\sum_n|k_n|^2|\phi(k_n)|^2\equiv||k\phi(k)||
$$

---

Then they say that $\prod_{i}\int d\phi(x_i)=\prod_{k_n}\int dRe(k_n)dIm(k_n)$ and argue is true because is a unitary transformation and it kinds of makes sense intuitively but I'm confused about how to actually calculate this, in any case I think without decomposing it in real and imaginary parts this should be $\prod_{i}\int d\phi(x_i)=\prod_{k_n}\int d\phi(k_n)$

Or using path integral notation
$$\int D\phi(x_i)\equiv\prod_{i}\int d\phi(x_i)=\prod_{k_n}\int d\phi(k_n)\equiv\int D\phi(k_n)$$

---

Next step would be to calculate the denominator, here we only need to know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi \over a}$, they decompose the norm in real and imaginary parts but I fail to see why this is necessary so boldly don't do so

$$
\int D\phi \exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)
=(\prod_{k_n}\int d\phi(k_n))\exp(-\frac{\sigma}{k_{B}TV}\sum_n|k_n|^2|\phi(k_n)|^2)
\\=\prod_{k_n}(\int d\phi(k_n)\exp(-\frac{\sigma|k_n|^2}{k_{B}TV}|\phi(k_n)|^2))
=\prod_{k_n}\sqrt{\frac{\pi k_{B}TV}{\sigma|k_n|^2}}
$$

Or using the notation for determinants
$$
\int D\phi \exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)\equiv\det{\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F}
$$

---

Now we need to calculate the numerator and like in the previous two steps again I don't use imaginary and real parts, I got lost in the analysis of how they decide which terms contribute and which don't so I simply copy-pasted to our case without much thinking.
$$
\int D\phi \langle\phi(x_i),\phi(x_j)\rangle\exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)
\\=\int D\phi (\frac{1}{V}\sum_n e^{-ik_nx_i}\phi(k_n))(\overline{\frac{1}{V}\sum_m e^{-ik_nx_j}\phi(k_m)})\exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)
\\=\int D\phi (\frac{1}{V^2}\sum_n\sum_m e^{i(k_mx_j-k_nx_i)}\phi(k_n)\overline{\phi(k_m)})\exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)
=(\prod_{k_l}\int d\phi(k_l))(\frac{1}{V^2}\sum_n\sum_m e^{i(k_mx_j-k_nx_i)}\phi(k_n)\overline{\phi(k_m)})\exp(-\frac{\sigma}{k_{B}TV^2}\sum_l|k_l|^2|\phi(k_l)|^2)
=_{somehow}(\prod_{k_l}\sqrt{\frac{\pi k_{B}TV}{\sigma|k_l|^2}}
)\frac{1}{V^2}\sum_n e^{ik_n(x_j-x_i)}\frac{k_{B}TV}{|k_n|^2}
\\=(\int D\phi \exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F))(\frac{k_{B}T}{\sigma})\frac{1}{V}\sum_n e^{ik_n(x_j-x_i)}\frac{1}{|k_n|^2}
\\=(\int D\phi \exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F))(\frac{k_{B}T}{\sigma})\int \frac{d^2 q}{(2\pi)^2}e^{iq(x_j-x_i)}\frac{1}{q^2}
$$

Or writing it as a fraction
$$
\frac{\int D\phi \langle\phi(x_i),\phi(x_j)\rangle\exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)
}{\int D\phi \exp(-\frac{\sigma}{2k_{B}T}F)}
=\frac{k_{B}T}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2 q}{(2\pi)^2}e^{iq(x_j-x_i)}\frac{1}{q^2}
$$

---

Finally

$$
\langle (h(\vec{y})-h(\vec{0}))^2\rangle
=\langle 0|(h(\vec{y})-h(\vec{0}))^2|0\rangle
=\langle 0|h(\vec{y})^2|0\rangle-2\langle 0|h(\vec{y})h(\vec{0})|0\rangle+\langle 0|h(\vec{0})^2|0\rangle
\\=\frac{k_{B}T}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2 q}{(2\pi)^2}e^{iq(\vec{y}-\vec{y})}\frac{1}{q^2}-2\frac{k_{B}T}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2 q}{(2\pi)^2}e^{iq(\vec{y}-\vec{0})}\frac{1}{q^2}+\frac{k_{B}T}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2 q}{(2\pi)^2}e^{iq(\vec{0}-\vec{0})}\frac{1}{q^2}
\\=\frac{2k_{B}T}{\sigma}\int \frac{d^2 q}{(2\pi)^2}(1-e^{iq\vec{y}})\frac{1}{q^2}
$$

Comment: I try to learn your instructive answer. One thing puzzles me is that why $\prod_{i}\int d\phi(x_i)=\prod_{k_n}\int d\phi(k_n)$. Why ${e^{ - i{k_n}{x_i}}}$ disappears in this transformation of integration variable. Would you please give me some help on it. Thanks!

Comment: @FaDA This is better explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291546/determinant-as-a-fermionic-path-integral), although it is not mentioned explicitly I think the point in that answer is that when we do change of variable we usually have to mutiply the new variable by a factor given by the determinant of the jacobian $dv=|\det(J)(u)|du$ with (J=Df, v=f(u)), or squaring $dvd\bar{v}=|\det(J)(u)|^2dud\bar{u}$, so in our case we could expect something like $\prod_{i}\int d\phi(x_i)=\prod_{k_n}\int d\phi(k_n)|\det(\%)|^2$ ...

Comment: ...but the fourier transform is unitary so we recover $\prod_{i}\int d\phi(x_i)=\prod_{k_n}\int d\phi(k_n)$, when I wrote the answer I wasn't sure myself what was happening so I will try to update it at some moment later so please let me know anything that is not clear about this or other point.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh! I have learned that